# how data in _open data view is recorded in SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, database, marketingcloudapi, data-views

As of now, our understanding of data views is that data is mostly real-time. But is this true for all data views or only specific data views? if specific, then which ones?

Recently, we noticed that we extracted ALL data from _open data views (on Dec 2) then in next run (on Dec 3), some new records showed up with open date Dec 1. How is this possible when Dec 2 records included opens from Dec 1. Then how come some records from older open date are showing up date view late?

I am trying to understand how data in _open data view gets collected to justify the late records with older open date.

Comment: I stopped treating Data views as necessarily real-time, in that I've observed _click/_open events without the respective _sent event that appeared an hour or so later. that said, I considered _open and _click to be the "less delayed" ones, but exceptions apparently apply. Opens are collected by 1) the SFMC server registering the open tracking pixel graphic being accessed once images in a mail are loaded by a recipient 2) [something in the backend] happening, "usually rather fast" 3) then the event showing up in the Data view. The problem is that we cannot observe 2) from the outside.

Comment: the official documentation doesn't help shed light on 2) either: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_clicks_and_opens_behavior.htm&type=5